# How to do HTTPS request from Phoenix and ignore the CA error

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to call a dev environment REST service from my phoenix server, but I don't want to whitelist the CA. For the record, I don't even know how to add the CA key to Phoenix's whitelist.

How to do https request from phoenix while also ignoring the SSL's CA error?

Comment: If I were you I'd be looking at either HTTPoison or HTTPotion.  I mean I think you'll find the information on making an SSL request in their documentation not in Phoenix's

Comment: already use HTTPoison, but still unable to set the `:insecure` in hackney

Comment: If the issue is that you're unable to set :insecure in hackney, maybe you want to append that to your question?

Comment: I'm expecting the answers would be an opinion or experience from either HTTPoison or HTTPotion users. But both options seem cant give me the easiest way to do what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [HTTPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison), you need to pass the `:insecure` hackney option.

```
HTTPoison.get! url, [], hackney: [:insecure]
```