# Elixir HTTPoison getting handshake_failure

Tags: curl, elixir, httpoison

This is my curl request

```
`curl --insecure --location --request POST 'url' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
  "client_id": "test"
}'
```

This worked fine!

Now this is my elixir request

```
HTTPoison.post("url", request, ssl: [verify: :verify_none])
```

Here I am getting error

```
    {:error,
 %HTTPoison.Error{
   id: nil,
   reason: {:tls_alert,
    {:handshake_failure,
     'TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:1783 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Handshake Failure\n {bad_cert,unable_to_match_altnames}'}}
 }}
```

`

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33205109/3474965

Comment: @sbacaro Thanks! using this also I am facing the same error

Comment: Forcing tls v1.2 is better than telling hackney to operate insecure

Answer (score 2):

You could try to force ssl to `tlsv1.2`.

```rb
HTTPoison.post("url", request, ssl: [versions: [:"tlsv1.2"]])
```

If this not works, try to remove `ssl` key and/or if you are using `hackney` you could try to configure with `insecure` option.

```rb
HTTPoison.post("url", request)

HTTPoison.post("url", request, [hackney: [:insecure]])

HTTPoison.post("url", request, [ssl: [versions: [:"tlsv1.2"]], hackney: [:insecure]])
```

By the way, which version of Erlang are you using?

The first recommendation was discussed [here](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/164).

Comment: forcing tls v1.2 is better than telling hackney to operate insecure